# EventMachine: I can't seem to pass a args to the Server's constructor (via start_server) or set things via block

Tags: ruby, eventmachine

I want to initialize an EventMachine server with an argument, but am having difficulty in doing so.

I have this code that starts a server:

```
port = APP_CONFIG.user['port']
Display.info "listening on port #{port}"
EM.start_server('0.0.0.0', port, Network::Local::Server) do |server|
  server.prepare(_message_dispatcher)
end
```

which I would expect would call `prepare` on this class:

```
  module Network
    module Local
      class Server < EM::Connection
        include EM::HttpServer
        attr_reader :_message_dispatcher, :_request_processor

        def prepare(message_dispatcher) # or initialize(message_dispatcher)
          puts 'hi'
          @_message_dispatcher = message_dispatcher
          @_request_processor = Decryption::RequestProcessor.new(
            network: NETWORK_LOCAL,
            message_dispatcher: message_dispatcher)
          puts 'done'
        end
        # ....
```

but the puts never get outputted to the console. I do however see `listening on port 8009` from right before I call `EM.start_server`

I've also tried this:

```
EM.start_server('0.0.0.0', port,
  Network::Local::Server, _message_dispatcher)
```

and then changed my `prepare` method to `initialize`, but I get the same results. The puts don't show in the console, but I do see `listening on port 8009`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: After digging around in the event machine code, it looks like the Server class is created with every http request. So that means the issue is with me sending requests.